# PropertyChanged event always null even after setting DataContext

Tags: wpf

I have a Model with `INotifyPropertyChanged` handling copied from tutorials:

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    protected void Notify(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

When I update a member of the class, I call the handler:

```
    public string? Id
    {
        get => _id;
        set
        {
            if (value != _id)
            {
                _id = value;
                Notify(nameof(Id));
            }
        }
    }
```

And in the view code behind I have:

```
    private Goal _goal;
    public GoalControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this._goal = new MyGoal();
        this.DataContext = _goal;
        Binding binding = new Binding("Text");
        binding.Source = _goal.Id;
        binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        _ = Id.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
    }
```

But the view doesn't pick up any changes to the field. When I debug, I find that `PropertyChanged` is always null. How should I set it to a useful value?

This is in a user control, by the way, which will be generated dynamically so I don't think I can do the binding from XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `Id` is a TextBox in your GoalControl, you would bind its Text property to the `Id` of the MyGoal object in the DataContext like shown below.

You do not set the `Source` property of the Binding, because the source object should be provided by the current DataContext. Also note that `TwoWay` is the default binding mode for the TextBox.Text property and does not need to be set explicitly.

```
public GoalControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _goal = new MyGoal();
    DataContext = _goal;

    Binding binding = new Binding("Id");
    Id.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
}
```

The Binding could as well be written in XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Id}"/>
```

---

Since this is in a UserControl, you should however not set the DataContext at all. UserControls, as any other controls, should not have "private" view models like your MyGoal object.

The UserControl would instead expose a dependency property `Id`, which is bound when you use the control, like

```
<local:GoalControl Id="{Binding SomeViewModelId}"/>
```

In the UserControl's XAML, the Binding to the own property would specify the Source object as RelativeSource:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Id,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. One day I'll get the hang of data binding!

Comment: What's the issue with local models, by the way? Every instance of this control must always be bound to a model and the model it's bound to must never change. I'm planning to pass the model in to the constructor (and yes, I already have code to expose it as a readonly public member) but that means I won't have a default constructor, so Visual studio won't show the design to me. This fix lets me see what I'm doing until I've finished the design.

Comment: "*I'm planning to pass the model in to the constructor*" - why that, instead of using the standard way of inheriting the DataContext? You don't "pass a model" to any framework control either. Those private view model serve no purpose. They are not connected to the view model structure of your application. And explicitly setting the DataContext of a control simply break standard, DataContext-based Bindings of its properties.

Comment: It doesn't make sense in my application for this control to inherit a data context. I could just set its data context to the model object without it internalising a reference to the object, but that seems to lay open the possibility of an instance of the view with no data context, whereas not allowing construction without a (non-nullable) model object seemed to be a way to avoid the possibility of that particular bug. But I suppose I could pass the data context in the constructor, retaining the link to the overall model - is that the sort of thing you mean?

Comment: Not at all. What I mean is that a control should not have a private view model at all. Controls just don't have view models. Their properties are bound to properties of view model of the views in which they live.

Comment: I can't make sense of that in my application. If my user creates a diagram with a pile of `Foo`s and a pile of `Bar`s, I need controls to render all those `Foo`s and controls to render all those `Bar`s, not the overall view model in which they live. Each model element needs its own visual representation that is manipulated independently. You seem to be considering a far more static layout - what I'm doing is more like Visio than Word - but maybe I'm missing something.